# Not able to run Java code using shell script from Desktop folder in ubuntu ,but works from opt folder

Tags: java, shell

On Ubuntu machine , I have a folder which contains shell script file ,folder with dependency jars and java project folder.

Ex:MAIN-FOLDER
          -SHELL SCRIPT FILE
          -JAVA PROJECT FOLDER
          -LIB FOLDER WITH JARS

In shell script I will be executing shell script from `MAIN-FOLDER` using below line :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -cp lib/*:JAVA_PROJECT-FOLDER/target/* com.ivizsecurity.scanoptions.MainClass $HOST $PORT $MYSQL_USER $MYSQL_PASSWORD
status=$?
```

So the problem is whenever I run shell script from opt folder in ubuntu it works fine , but if i try to copy the same folder in desktop and execute,it throws below error . It is not able to access `lib` folder

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
      at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
      at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:464)
      at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:310)
      at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:146)
      at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1169)
      at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
      at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:288)
      at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:277)
      at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:400)
      at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
      at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
```

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below command in Ubuntu.

In bash shell, type below command.

`sudo chmod -r 777 /your main folder` <-- Press Enter

It will ask for password, enter password.

Then execute the shell script with sudo, I mean `sudo sh yourshellscript.sh`.

Comment: I alreay tried with giving permission .But still didn't work .If I check lib folder it shows all the permission    drwxrwxrwx 2 ABC ABC 4096 Jun  5 07:21 lib.

Comment: It will work from Desktop folder only if I modify lib path to opt/lib        Ex:                                                                                           /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -cp /opt/lib/:JAVA_PROJECT-FOLDER/target/ com.ivizsecurity.abc.MainClass $HOST $PORT $MYSQL_USER $MYSQL_PASSWORD status=$?.                                                                                                          I have replaced lib/* to /opt/lib/*.    But I dont want to refer from opt

Comment: It works from opt, it means, it has full access. Give the same level of access, I mean 777 and try. While running the shell script file, run with sudo.